# Confluence Macro Browser autocompletion for attachments

Tags: plugins, macros, confluence

I am trying to show all attachments (from the current page) in an auto-completed drop-down list. This is the part in the atlassian-plugin.xml which defines the parameters:

```
<xhtml-macro name="plugin-name" class="com.example.macro.name" key="macroname-xhtml" icon="/download/resources/${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}/icons/macroname.png">
    <category name="formatting"/>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="content_input" type="confluence-content" />
        <parameter name="space_input" type="spacekey" />
        <parameter name="attachment_input" type="attachment" />
    </parameters>
</xhtml-macro>
```

The `confluence-content` and `spacekey` types work just fine. It shows a textfield which autocompletes Pages and Spaces.

However, the `attachment` type shows a empty drop-down list (select box) which cannot auto-complete.

The official Confluence documentation says it should work like I do:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Including+Information+in+your+Macro+for+the+Macro+Browser

I must be missing something here, but I don't know what. Anyone might know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a drop-down list with all the attachments then you may also try the following:

```
<xhtml-macro name="plugin-name" class="com.example.macro.name" key="macroname-xhtml" icon="/download/resources/${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}/icons/macroname.png">
    <category name="confluence-content" />
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="page" type="confluence-content" required="false"
            multiple="false" />
        <parameter name="name" type="attachment" required="false" />
    </parameters>
</xhtml-macro>
```

- Don't change the names of the parameters

If you want to add a filter, then you need the following:

```
<web-resource key="macro-browser-smart-fields" name="Macro Browser Smart Fields">
    <resource type="download" name="confluence-core-macro-fields.js" location="js/confluence-core-macro-fields.js" />
    <dependency>confluence.editor.actions:editor-macro-browser</dependency>
    <context>macro-browser</context>
</web-resource>
```

confluence-core-macro-fields.js

```
(function($) {
    AJS.MacroBrowser.activateSmartFieldsAttachmentsOnPage("plugin-name", [ "png", "jpg", "gif" ]);
})(AJS.$);
```

Comment: This is a better option than mine as yours is capable of filtering on file extensions.

Comment: And it lists already existing files to the user in a dropdown list. Autocompletion is nice but only if unknow the attachment file name.

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting the type as `attachment` (following official documentation) is bugged. I have found a work-around to display attachments in a auto-complete box.

```
<parameter name="xsd" type="confluence-content" required="true">
    <option key="type" value="attachment"/>
    <option key="showKeyInPlaceholder" value="false" />
    <option key="showValueInPlaceholder" value="true" />
</parameter>
```

Comment: How do you limit the attachment search to current pages only?
The above will list out any matching filenames in the entire confluence